# WcfCommunicationListener vs FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I inherited some SF services that uses WcfCommunicationListener. For new SF services (statelss or stateful), I use the default FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener. So just wondering, what are the advantages/disadvantages of using one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

`WcfCommunicationListener` gives you [a *very* wide range of options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb945107.aspx) when if comes to configuring how you communicate with your service. For instance, you can choose different protocols, you can add different features of the communication such as security, encryption, signatures and auditing by [modifying the binding](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/different-types-of-binding-in-wcf/) you use. If you need to expose your service to other clients that are not necessarily .NET then WCF gives you a lot of choices to choose a communication model that fits.

`FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener` on the other is very easy to use when communicating between Reliable Services. It also gives you a lot of out-of-the-box features on both client and service side, such as handling communication specific exceptions and retrying them and setting up certificate-based secure communication. Fabric Transport is limited to RPC-style communication for .NET clients.

There is nothing that prevents you from having both a `WcfCommunicationListener` and a `FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener` for the same service, just set up both in your service (on different ports) and your clients can choose which one to use.

Comment: As far as communication with the client, these services will be exposed via a RESTful API gateway so Wcf will not have the benefits of the options you mentioned.

Comment: Do you mean that you have your own RESTful API service that your external clients connect to and that in turn communicates with your services (using either WCF or FabricTransport)? If that is the case and then I see no benefit to using WCF communication as opposed to FabricTransport.

Comment: There are existing services that uses the Wcf. For the new services, I use the default. Since I already have a proxy wrapper for my default communication and kinda dont want to create a wcf proxy wrapper, I just added a new communication listener which uses the default. That works for me. I am just wondering what the benefits/disadvantage of using one over the other.

Comment: The advantage of using WCF would mainly be if you have services that you wish to expose _outside_ of your cluster and the clients cannot (for whatever reason) use FabricTransport. I can't see any benefit to using WCF for communicating between services inside a cluster. I suppose you might have some requirements for the communication that a specific binding in WCF could satisfy, like out of the box signed messages, messages with exactly-once delivery guarantee and so on, but I find it had to see that those requriments couldn't be satisfied by extending the FabricTransport instead...